# Regional and Language Options >> Customize in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

I can not the find the below path in Windows 7.

Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > select Customize on the Regional Options tab > change the List separator to a pipe "|"

I am trying to change the default settings of excel workbook, the excel sheet when converted to text file is **tab** delimited. *I want the default to **pipe***.

I googled and found the above result, to change the default delimited settings. But I can not do this in Win7 Control Panel >> Regional and Language.

How can I do this in Win 7 OS. *Is this an XML file, if yes how can I edit this file*?

Comment: Language packs on windows 7 only are on certain versions of windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I navigate it like this.... see image left to right in sequence...I hope this will be of some help[image]

Comment: I tried the solution, but it did not work. I found the same solution in (http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2008/07/09/windows-xp-hack-how-to-use-a-pipe-quotquot-delimiter.aspx).

**I changed the settings then used VB to change excel to text**. My code is:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Stuff\CX852QE", FileFormat:=xlCurrentPlatformText`